# attached vs connected

Tags: meaning, word-choice, technical

I am confused with the two words, which one technically has a broader meaning? and maybe including another one,

or you have alternative that could include both, thanks.

Comment: What have you found out so far from dictionaries?

Comment: WiFi is connected but not attached.

Comment: @StuartF I think you can get away with saying that your phone is attached to the WiFi network. Both "attached" and "connected" are used somewhat figuratively for wireless networks.

Comment: I think the two words are mostly interchangeable. There are some contexts where one is more idiomatic than the other, but I don't think there's any hierarchy to the meanings.

Comment: *Connected* is definitely more common than attached for WiFi, e.g. [this](https://www.speedefy.com/article/10-solutions-if-wifi-is-connected-but-no-internet-connection/), [this](https://lazyadmin.nl/home-network/wifi-connected-but-no-internet-fix-it-in-5-min/), although this probably doesn't apply for all services (I see *attach* with Bluetooth). There are various technical contexts where different words are preferred, but the question should be more precise. (Also *attached* has romantic senses such as "fond of" or "in a relationship", although *connected* can mean something similar.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can discern between the two, it ultimately depends on your context and, perhaps, more importantly - your intent. For instance, if you have more poetic designs, the different definitions may be useful. However, if it is simply clinical (context aside) I believe most people will read them interchangeably. Etymologically speaking there is a difference. Providing more context for your use would be helpful, as these two words are already rather broad in their definitions.

Comment: what I want to express is the two panels physically against each other and fixated by approximate mean depending on the material, such as wood, glass, metal etc....you may come up with.   I prefer ATTACH if I am correct, but different material may need different meaning of attachment.

Answer (score 0):

'Connected' is broader. 'Attached' implies a robust, direct, physical connection.

A) Two concepts can be 'connected' but they cannot be 'attached'; 'attached' is only physical, while 'connected' can also be figurative.

B) Two train stations are 'connected' but not 'attached'; 'attached' means directly adjacent, while 'connected' can also mean that there is an indirect path.

C) A loose computer cable is 'connected' but not 'attached'; 'attached' implies that it's anchored, while 'connected' can also mean slightly touching.

However, 'attached' is also used in some cases that do not fit my definitions. For example: a file may be 'attached' to an email, or a pet may be 'attached' to their owner. This seems to be using the connotations of the word to conjure certain imagery of direct physical attachment.

Comment: You need to supply evidence from reputable source. I down voted because I would choose the opposite pairing for one of your instances, and I disagree that any hierarchy exists in general, only is some specific jargons, and which way that works varies.